# Can't get beginTime and endTime to work when creating new calendar event

Tags: android, calendar, unix-timestamp

When I create my calendar event I use a unix timestamp from a JSON that's a string and then I convert it to a long, but somehow I'm not getting it to work properly.

```
setReminder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, Long.parseLong(start));
                intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
                intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1");
                //intent.putExtra("endTime", end);
                intent.putExtra("title", title + " by " + artist);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479146/add-event-to-calendar-api-7/21479776#21479776

Comment: can You give us a bit more details? WHAT is not working?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs It doesn't set the correct time when I get to the calendar event creation activity, either it just picks a time seemingly at random or it sets it to the closest hour.

Comment: then please show how You get the start and end time.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Like I said before, I get it from a JSON online, then I get the timestamp from there. It's not the timestamp itself that is the problem since I'm using it in other parts of my app to display the time and date, it's just when I try to create a calendar event that it's not working. I think maybe the calendar needs it in another format or something? But the docus said it should be millis from epoch.

Comment: if the time is wrong, the important part is to see Your Calendar actions..

Comment: @Opiatefuchs What do you mean with my calendar actions?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem and I have myself to blame. I should've posted all my code and I'm sure someone would've gotten it before me.

I was trying to set this from an onclicklistener attached to a button in a recycled view. Since the view was being recycled it would sometimes get time info from a totally different place than what I actually wanted.

Instead of keeping it inside the null checker for my view I moved it outside of it and everything worked.

Sorry for the trouble, I shouldn't expect to get answers if I can't even provide the proper information to start with.